# .net web application in IIS Swapping Folder without appdomain reload

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-8, asp.net-mvc

I've a asp mvc application running on IIS and windows.

Now I want to configure some kind of staging functionality without requiring an additional server.

My simplified plan is to have 2 folders. One with the production release and one which gets the new deployment.

After deployment i would warm up caches and then swap production with staging. But when I change the binding or folder it seems like the application is reloaded and therefore the data from the warmup is lost.

How can I achieve the desired behavior ? Is there  a better way (tools ?) for realizing a staging process?

Answer (score 0):

As recommended some while ago on Stack Overflow you like to use a reverse proxy in front of your two "instances" of your web site:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970058/mimic-azure-staging-on-custom-server/25980245#25980245

As you only change settings in the public facing web site your two instances remain untouched and therefore do not reload their AppDomain. You might like to checkout nginx or Apache httpd for this kind of handling.

Regards, JoKi